# Accessing elements of return array from method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, element, return-type

I'm a novice Java programmer and I have a question! 
I would like to access elements of an array without reactivating the following method each time:

```
public static int[] getValues(){
  int[] vals = new int[2];
  System.out.println("I only want this to print once");
  //as an example just populating a simple array of size 2:
  vals[0] = 1;
  vals[1] = 2;
  return vals;
}
```

now in my main method, when I want to access int[0] and int[1], how do I without reactivating the entire method again enabling that print statement to print twice?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  x = getValues()[0];
  y = getValues()[1];
  System.out.println("x and y: "+x+" "+y);
}
```

This gives an output:

```
I only want this to print once
I only want this to print once
x and y: 1 2
```

Comment: Are you asking how to assign the value returned by a method to a variable and reuse that variable?

Comment: Just do `int[] values = getValues();` in your `main` method. Then do `x = values[0]` to retrieve the first value. Change the index for other positions.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I want to access vals[0] and vals[1] without activating the method each time. When I do x = getValues()[0] and y = getValues()[1], it prints the statement of in the method twice when I want it to only print once.